# Recursive Algorithm Complexity?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, big-o

I had the following question before:

Given a recursive algorithm **T(n)**, Find a function **f(n)** for which
[image: T(n)=\theta( f(n) )].

**Note:** **k** is constant and **> 3**, and for **n<=1**, **T(n)=0**.

[image: T(n)=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{\log n} T\left(\left\lfloor \frac{n}{k^i} \right\rfloor\right)\right) + n]

How can I solve such question?

Comment: What is theta here?  Seems like this is a pure math question.

Comment: @Brick It's related to Big-O. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations

Comment: I can see that it's omega(n), but how to prove it's O(n)?

Comment: @daniel What's Omega(n)? Did you find a function?

Comment: can't you use latex or math notation rather than image for the formulas?

Comment: @Kristian Sadly, not on this site. The closest thing I could find was the google charts api which lets you pass Latex data as GET parameters, which is actually an edit I made earlier. Only trouble is you have to URL encode the thing.

Comment: just confirmed that latex and mathjax cannot be used in SO. I assumed it can since I used it in math.stackexchange a few years ago.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow daniel. It would be nice to show your understanding so far and present a problem where you are stuck. Otherwise seems like you just need a quick homework-solver.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I won't show all my steps. This is your homework problem, but here's an overview:

- Based on the recursion definition, we can break down the summation:

  ```
  T(n) = 
      n 
    + T(floor(n / k)) 
    + T(floor(n / k ^ 2)) 
    + ... 
    + T(floor(n / (k ^ log(n))))
  ```
- Then from this, we can get an iterative definition:

  ```
    T(n) = 
        n 
        + floor(n / k) 
        + 2 * floor(n / k ^ 2) 
        + ... 
        + 2 ^ (log(n) - 1) 
            * floor(n / k ^ (log(n)))
  ```

  or

  ```
  T(n) = 
    n 
    + Sum(
        floor(n / k ^ i) * 2 ^ (i), 
        i=1, log(n)
    ) / 2
  ```

Your question asks for big Theta. This means we need to figure out an upper and lower bound.

- Upper bound: `floor(x) <= x`, so we drop the floor and simplify:

  ```
  O(
      n + n / (k - 2)                       <-- O(n)
      + (n * (2 / k) ** log(n)) / (k - 2)
  )
  ```

  Because `k > 3 > 2`, the final term is guaranteed to grow less than `n`, so we're left with `O(n)`.
- Lower bound: The `Sum(...) > 0` always, so we can bound it below with just `n`, giving `Omega(n)`.

Because `T` is both `O(f(n))` and `Omega(f(n))` for `f(n) = n`, we can say that it is also `Theta(n)`, so an answer would be

```
f(n) = n
```

---

Here's a program that demos an upper and lower bound. This program is not the equivalent of a proof, but it can help you see what's going on. I grew `n` exponentially, so if you plot the values on a log scale, it should show the lines and the asymptotic behavior.

```js
const k = 4;
const logK = Math.log(k);

function T(n) {
  if (n <= 1)
   return 0;
  
  let acc = n;
  for (let i = 1; i <= Math.log(n) / logK; i++)
    acc += T(Math.floor(n * k ** -i));
  
  return acc;
}

function nonRecT(n) {
  let acc = n;
  for (let i = 1; i <= Math.log(n) / logK; i++) {
    let f = Math.floor(n * k ** -i);
    acc += f > 1 ? f * 2 ** (i - 1) : 0;
  }
  return acc;
}

for (let n = k; n <= k ** 20; n *= k) {
  console.log([
    n,
    T(n), nonRecT(n),
    n * (1.5 + 1 / (k - 2))
  ].join('\t'));
}
```